# Maven cannot download spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.6

Tags: spring, maven

I'm having problems with maven. I created new module with Intellij IDEA, and using terminal:

`./mvnw clean install`

It started to download all dependencies, but it freezes on

`Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.6.RELEASE.pom`

Comment: How long did you wait? Maybe it is just downloading the files. It can take a while if you have a slow connection.

Comment: Are you on a restrictive network that blocks `repo.maven.apache.org`? or requires network authentication?

Comment: Network is very fast, it's home computer. There is not restrictions. It downloads more then 10 other dependencies and then freezes.

Comment: If you are getting a time out exception most probably must be an issue with either your network, or their repository server. If its the latter then try after sometime. A more manual brute force approach might be deleting the artifacts from you .m2 repository and trying again.